# How can I create a multi select dropdown plugin in ckeditor5?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor5

I want to create a custom plugin with **mulitselect dropdown** to apply multiple style classes to editor content.

Ckeditor-version4 has similar dropdown component with multiselect option(ui.richCombo). Does ckeditor5 provide any api/ui componenent support for this requirement?

Can someone help me with the approach?
Any help will be appreciated.